the order of $R=\Bbb{Z}[x]/(ax+b, x^2+5)$ is $5a^2+b^2$
Let $a,b \in \Bbb{Z}$. When $a\neq 0$, I want to prove the order of $R=\Bbb{Z}[x]/(ax+b, x^2+5)$ is $5a^2+b^2$.
$R\cong \Bbb{Z}[-b/a]/((-b/a)^2+5)$. If I could prove the last ring is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}/(5a^2+b^2)$, we are done.
Is my approach correct ? If so, how can I prove $R\cong \Bbb{Z}/(5a^2+b^2)$ ?
Note that this question is the same as asking the order of $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]/(a+b\sqrt{-1})$.
This follows from general theory, that is, norm of principal ideal is the same as the norm of generator. But here, I want to give elementary proof by calculating residue ring.

How do you know that this can be proven to be the case?

As noted in the other answer, $R$ is in general not cyclic (as an abelian group under addition). Here is one proof of the result, which also reveals when $R$ is cyclic (which implies it is a quotient of $\mathbb{Z}$).
Let $S = \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+5)$, so $R \cong S/(ax+b)$. As a group under addition, $S$ is a free abelian group with basis $\{1,x\}$, and the ideal $I = (ax+b)$ of $S$ is generated by $ax+b$ and $x(ax+b) = bx-5a$. In other words, in the basis $\{1,x\}$, $I$ is generated by the columns of the matrix
$$ A = \begin{bmatrix} b & -5a \\ a & b \end{bmatrix}. $$
Now we use the structure theorem for finitely generated abelian groups. The Smith normal form of $A$ (over $\mathbb{Z}$) is the diagonal matrix $\operatorname{diag}(a_1, a_2)$, where $a_1 = \gcd(a,b)$ is the gcd of the entries of $A$, and $a_1 a_2 = \det A$. Then we have (as abelian groups)
$$R \cong S/I \cong \mathbb{Z}/(a_1) \oplus \mathbb{Z}/(a_2),$$
where $a_1$ divides $a_2$. Now $\det A = 5a^2 + b^2 > 0$ because of the assumption $a\ne 0$, so $a_1$ and $a_2$ are nonzero and
$$|R| = |a_1 a_2| = |{\det A}| = 5a^2 + b^2.$$
Moreover, $R$ is cyclic if and only if $|a_1| = 1$, which is equivalent to $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

Could you tell me the reason why $S/I \cong \Bbb{Z}/(a_1)\otimes \Bbb{Z}/(a_2)$ ?

@Poitou-Tate It's a direct sum, not a tensor product. It's directly from the structure theorem; specifically the invariant factor version. Briefly: $I$ and $S$ are free abelian groups of rank $2$ hence isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$; the inclusion $I \hookrightarrow S$ has the Smith normal form of $A$ as its matrix in some basis, so the quotient is a sum of cyclic groups given by the diagonal entries (i.e. the invariant factors).

You cannot prove the isomorphism $R\simeq \mathbb{Z}/(5a^2+b^2)\mathbb{Z}$, because its false.
As you noted implicitely, $R\simeq \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]/(a\sqrt{-5}+b)$.
So, you want to prove that there is a ring isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]/(a\sqrt{-5}+b)\simeq \mathbb{Z}/(5a^2+b^2)\mathbb{Z}$.
In particular, it would mean that the class $-5$ of is a square in $\mathbb{Z}/(5a^2+b^2)\mathbb{Z}$, for all $a,b$, $a\neq 0$.
This is clearly not the case. Take $a=2$ and $b=0$. Then $-5$ is not a square modulo $5a^2+b=20$, since $-5$ is not a square modulo $4$.
